# Xcode Swift 5 MacOs app empty window when archived but works when running it from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am building an app for Mac which logs into a website based on login and password collected from textfield and secure text field, then app opens an url which is created in my app based on date range selection with use of two date picker cell calendars. Next app displays html data in webWiev (using WKWebView), converts html to string using extension NSAttributedString and then saves retrieved data as txt file. Everything works as expected as long as app is run from Xcode "play" button. Problem is if I archive this app and launch it, it will bring up an empty window without any button, calendar or textfield. There are no errors, no crash logs on organizer, nothing.

I decided to perform a little test. I build another view controller with only one button which upon clicking will show my app main view controller. After archiving this modified app and running it outside of Xcode a window shows view controller with one button which is correct. But after clicking it nothing happens. App works great if running "inside" Xcode, a pushbutton shows main ViewController correctly. Do You have any clue what can be wrong? thank You!

**Edit 1.** So I found a discussion on apple which mention this problem. It is associated with IB WKWebView and problem is already known since some time. Now I have to get around the problem. Apple forum link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116047

Comment: Did you check console? I got prints:

Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (WKWebView) for key (NS.objects) because no class named "WKWebView" was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target). If the class was renamed, use setClassName:forClass: to add a class translation mapping to NSKeyedUnarchiver

Answer (score 3):

Did you embed WebKit.framework to your app?

After comment that I wrote, I founded a solution and solved with this method.

Please check it out.

[image: Embedded WebKit]

Comment: I had the same problem, WKWebView was working fine when launching app from Xcode, but Apple was rejecting it because of the crash "cannot decode object of class (WKWebView)". Adding WebKit.framework solved this.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Had the same issue. Thank you @CenoX